# How do you set the default value of a UUID attribute in core data xcdatamodel

Tags: swift, core-data

How do you set the default value of a UUID attribute in the core data xcdatamodel.
if I set the attribute as non-optional it requires a default value.
in code I'd set it using UUID() to assign a value but this doesn't work in the xcdatamodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to assign a default value in the model.

In the class override `awakeFromInsert`

```
override func awakeFromInsert() {
    super.awakeFromInsert()
    uuid = UUID()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me as I get error in the xcdatamodel that the field needs a default value. Unable to set a default value for UUID.

Comment: Very strange. I'm using this way in a few projects. Did you declare the type of the attribute as UUID?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly if it is required or not. I believe that it IS required, at least according to Xcode reports, WHEN using CloudKit.

Comment: When using CloudKit, this crashes if not Optional.  This answer does not seem to work.  I have fallen back to changing my id types to Strings and using `UUID().uuidString` then they can just have an empty string default value in the Attributes inspector.

Comment: rbaldwin - CloudKit and CoreData require all attributes to be optional. this function sets the UUID so its always populated. You shouldnt untick the Optional box in your xcdatamodel ever. I'm surprised you even got it to compile. Set your uuid attribute to optional and put the awakeFromInsert function in your ManagedObject Class file for the relevant entity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string representation of any `UUID()` value as a default. For example: `0CF044A3-333C-4B22-8FEB-F68B004B6C96` could be a default.

To quickly generate a new UUID a terminal could be used. Just type `swift repl` there and then `import Foundation` and then `print(UUID())`. This will give you a new random UUID.

[image: Default UUID in CoreData]

Comment: The command is now `swift repl` (not just simply `swift`) to get a fast UUID.

Comment: This answer reminds me of the classic xkcd comic: `func getRandomNumber() -> { return 4 // Chosen by fair dice row, guaranteed to be random  }` https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: That's because it's a requirement to provide a constant here as a default value isn't it?

Comment: The answer has been updated to use `swift repl`.

Answer (score -7):

Please satisfy the **Identifiable** protocol to get the UUID() work.